# jQuery update event and DOM event is not working with popover tag handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tag-handler

I am not able to call jQuery’s `update` event for popover with `live` event.

Is there any way that I don't need to reinitialize the popover on each `live` event.

I have tried using `$(selector).action()`, but it's not working.

Is there any way that i can initialize the popover on DOM `live` event without calling its initialize method?

Comment: Please share your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.